# Python json dump

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{"environment": "production", 
 "classes": 
    {"nfs::server": {"exports": ["/srv/share1","/srv/share3"]}}
}
```

When I run the following code using Python 3.6

```
fp=open('example.json', 'r')
data=json.load(fp)

print(50*'-')
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
print(50*'-')
json.dump(data, sys.stdout, indent=4)
```

I get the output:

```
--------------------------------------------------
{
    "environment": "production",
    "classes": {
        "nfs::server": {
            "exports": [
                "/srv/share1",
                "/srv/share3"
            ]
        }
    }
}
--------------------------------------------------
{
    "environment": "production",
    "classes": {
        "nfs::server": {
            "exports": [
                "/srv/share1",
                "/srv/share3"
            ]
        }
    }
}%
```

My question is why is the extra `%` included in the `json.dump` output compared to the `json.dumps` string?   It is not an artifact of the OS because if I provide a file object instead of `sys.stdout` it also gets written to the file.

Comment: Could this be an artifact of an encoding mismatch?

Comment: Issue observable only using `zsh`, not using `bash`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last % is the first character of your console prompt line
or a feature of your shell (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167582/why-zsh-ends-a-line-with-a-highlighted-percent-symbol)

Nothing to do with json, nor python.

Because, when print() add a '\n' at the end, the dump to stdout doesn't

Comment: Why would the first character of the console prompt be written to a file?

Comment: it does not :) sys.stdout is not a file, it's the standard output (ie. console). What the OP copy-pasted may be what was displayed in his console... hence the spurious % char

Comment: *"if I provide a file object instead of `sys.stdout` it also gets written to the file. "* - so how does your answer explain this part?

Comment: because, if the OP does a `cat file.txt`, the result is the same, with not trailing `\n`, he see the next % of the prompt :) (just a guess)

Comment: '%' is no part of my console prompt

Comment: you are right, me neither, but when I forget the trailing `\n` I still get a %: `echo -n tutu` `tutu%`... It may still be due to the shell behavior and not python

Comment: I think it is a shell thing.  Although I have no % in my shell prompt (using `zsh`), if I switch to `bash` this problem disappears.  Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: I just had the same thing happen using zsh. Adding a newline fixed it. Good to know.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))` prints a newline, and `json.dump(data, sys.stdout, indent=4)` does not.

You can try adding a `print()` at the end:

```
print(50*'-')
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
print(50*'-')
json.dump(data, sys.stdout, indent=4)
print()
```

Is the `%` symbol part of your shell's prompt?

Comment: While this solves the problem of output to the console, it does not solve output to a file, ie. replace `sys.stdout` with a file object.  My shell prompt has no `%` but it is still output to a file when using `json.dump`

Comment: It's ultimately a shell issue, using `zsh` I observe the trailing `%` but with bash no trailing `%`.  Thanks for the help guys.